# how can I count total number of keyValues in array of object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

i got the array of dictionary in CartDataModal structure

```
class CartDataModal: NSObject {
    static let shared_Inst = CartDataModal()
    var cartArrayDict = [[String:Any]]()
}
```

the received data is in format below

restmenu is after inserting

```
[
["ItemName": Cheese Burger, "ItemPrice": 50, "ItemQuant": "2"], 
["ItemName": Veg Burger, "ItemPrice": 30, "ItemQuant": 0], 
["ItemName": Chicken Burger, "ItemPrice": 50, "ItemQuant": 0], 
["ItemName": Veg & Crisp Burger, "ItemPrice": 45, "ItemQuant": 0], 
["ItemName": Maharaja Burger, "ItemPrice": 60, "ItemQuant": 0], 
["ItemName": Coke, "ItemPrice": 50, "ItemQuant": 0], 
["ItemName": Pepsi, "ItemPrice": 50, "ItemQuant": 0]
]
```

how can i count the total number of keyValues for "ItemQuant"?

Comment: You can use `cartArrayDict.count` for the total number of `ItemName`, if `ItemName` are not duplicate. You can add it into set to remove the redundancy.

Comment: I'll try those two then inform you guys]

Comment: It worked thnx for help

Comment: @GurjitSingh, you needed array of `ItemNames` ?

Comment: currently I need total number of "ItemQuant" combined to display it in cart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to count the number of items in the `cartArrayDict` while ensuring that only those keys that are `"ItemName"` are included. It uses the `reduce()` function of the array with the desired key of the dictionary, with a nil coalescing operator in case the key does not exist.

**How to get count of items (by key) in array of dictionaries**

```
let count: Int = cartArrayDict.reduce(0) {
    $0 + ($1["ItemName"] != nil ? 1 : 0)
}
print(count) // Or do whatever you want with the value
```

**How to get total sum of quantities**

Here is how to get total sum of the quantities, as asked in comments.

```
let totalQuantity: Int = cartArrayDict.reduce(0) {
    $0 + ($1["ItemQuant"] as? Int ?? 0)
}
print(totalQuantity) // Or do whatever you want with the value
```

**How to get total price for one type of item**

I have presented this as a function.

```
func getTotalPrice(for name: String) -> Int {
    let totalPrice: Int = cartArrayDict.reduce(0) {
        $0 + ($1["ItemName"] == name ? $1["ItemPrice"] as? Int : 0)
    }
    return totalPrice
}

let totalPriceForCoke = getTotalPrice(for: "Coke")
```

Note that this assumes the values for key `"ItemName"` are `String` type. At present your values are not strings and I am not sure why this should be. I suggest changing it like this: `"Coke"` instead of `Coke`.

Comment: but what if I want that for "ItemQuant" to get the quantity for my status bar? its returning 0 for that

Comment: @GurjitSingh I have updated answer to make it more generalisable. Just change string "ItemName" to "ItemQuant". Note that this will count the number of elements that have an item quantity, not the total combined quantity. Do you need the total quantity added together?

Comment: actually I need total number of quantity to display for number of items in cart

Comment: @GurjitSingh The second part of my answer should provide that.

Comment: it only returning 0 always

Comment: Most of your item quantities above are zero, so adding them will return zero. The first one has a quantity of two but the two is a string, not an integer ("2" instead of 2). Try making it an integer.

Comment: got it what you are saying @Chris, but I need a last help what i need is, i want the total sum from the SecdDict["ItemPrice"] from every object with the same keyValue

Comment: Okay, just to check, you need total price of each type of item. For example, total price of all Coke, or all Cheese Burger? I think your types like Coke and Cheeseburger should be String type with quotation marks (" ").

Comment: Thnx @Chris you made my day bro big respect bro

Comment: @GurjitSingh No problem! 

Comment: By the way, my code uses the ternary conditional operator and nil coalescing operator, which are very useful. You can find more information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: I'm friendly with that @Chris

Comment: @GurjitSingh I thought you would know about it, but I gave more info just in case :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the array of dictionary:

```
var cartArrayDict = [[String:Any]]()
```

You need to map the `cartArrayDict` to get array of `ItemName` :

```
let itemNames: [String] = cartArrayDict.map( { $0["ItemName"] }) as? [String]
```

To remove duplicate values just pass it into `Set` and reconvert into array:

```
let itemNameArray = Array(Set(itemNames))
```

**In total, You can find out the ItemNameArray as:**

```
    let cartArrayDict = [
        ["ItemName": "Cheese Burger", "ItemPrice": 50, "ItemQuant": "2"],
        ["ItemName": "Veg Burger", "ItemPrice": 30, "ItemQuant": 0],
        ["ItemName": "Chicken Burger", "ItemPrice": 50, "ItemQuant": 0],
        ["ItemName": "Veg & Crisp Burger", "ItemPrice": 45, "ItemQuant": 0],
        ["ItemName": "Coke", "ItemPrice": 60, "ItemQuant": 0],
        ["ItemName": "Coke", "ItemPrice": 50, "ItemQuant": 0],
        ["ItemName": "Pepsi", "ItemPrice": 50, "ItemQuant": 0]
    ]

    if let itemsArr = cartArrayDict.map( { $0["ItemName"] }) as? [String] {
        let itemNameArray = Array(Set(itemsArr))
        print(itemNameArray)
    }

    // Result: ["Veg Burger", "Chicken Burger", "Pepsi", "Cheese Burger", "Coke", "Veg & Crisp Burger"]
```

Comment: Please don't use force unwrap `!` in an Swift answer especially to a beginner. Take the time to provide a non-lethal answer. Thanks

Comment: @Moritz, I think user wants the total number of ItemName in the line "how can i count the total number of keyValues for "ItemName".

Comment: @Moritz, updated the code for force unwrapping `!` and converted the `Set` to `Array` again